# Falha no servidor hhvm

Tags: hack, hhvm

Criei um projeto escolar para utilizar a linguagem Hack.

Realizei a instalação do `hhvm` conforme documentação

```
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

Iniciei o servidor

```
hhvm -m server -p 8080
```

E criei um arquivo chamado `selectPost.hh` que nele contém apenas a tag inicial

```
<?hh
   //Nao tem mais nada
```

Quando abro o navegador e tento executar o meu arquivo ele não funciona. No log do terminal gera o seguinte:

> Fatal error: /home/usuario/Documentos/web/ajax/selectPost.hh appears
>   to be a Hack file, but you do not appear to be running the Hack
>   typechecker.

Não entendi como faço para eu conseguir executar um arquivo no servidor.

Alguém sabe qual configuração faltou eu realizar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

Na raiz do diretório do seu projeto, crie um arquivo vazio com o nome `.hhconfig`. O verificador de tipo usa este arquivo para saber qual árvore de diretório para verificar tipo, sem precisar especificar caminhos para cada comando.